# Is it possible to use highlight in elasticsearch-js?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I am developing the following code snippet:

```
app.get('/search', function (req, res){
  let body = {
    size: 200,
    from: 0, 
    highlight: {
      pre_tags : ["<tag1>"],
      post_tags : ["</tag1>"],
      fields: {
        "_content" : {}
      }
    }
  }
  client.search({index:'juridico',  q: req.query['q'], body: body})
  .then(results => {
    console.log(results);
    res.send(results.hits.hits);
  })
  .catch(err=>{
    console.log(err)
    res.send([]);
  });

})
```

But when I pass the highlight parameter on the body, I do not get it in response.

Answer (score 0):

I had to finagle the fields in body around like this:

```
let body = {
  highlight: {
    require_field_match: false,
    fields: {
      '*': {
        pre_tags: ['<span>'],
        post_tags: ['</span>']
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I used a `'*'` here as a wildcard to search on all fields. I believe you can also use it if you want to search on many fields that have the same pre/post-fix. Hope this works out for you!

Comment: Do you have the example of the method?

Comment: `esClient.search({
   index: '_all',
   body: {
    query: {
     bool: {
      must: [{
       multi_match: {
        query: req.query.query,
        fuzziness: 'AUTO',
       },
      }],
      filter: [{
       term: { test: req.query.test },
      }],
     },
    },
    highlight: {
     require_field_match: false,
     fields: {
      '*': {
       pre_tags: ['<span>'],
       post_tags: ['</span>'],
      },
     },
    },
   },
  })`

Sorry I can't format it better.